# What is BackendFactory in context of react dnd?

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I am trying to implement the [react-chessboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chessboard) component. I want a page that contains an empty chessboard and the pieces are kept outside for the user to drag and drop them into the board. By default the board is set to the starting position.
In the react-chessboard documentation, I came across a prop called 'customDndBackend' which takes a value of type BackendFactory. I could not find it anywhere so I asked it here. Any help would be appreciated.
[react-chessboard-npm page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlNBN.png)

```js
<Chessboard
                className={classes.board}
                boardWidth={
                    window.screen.width < 600 ? 0.9 * window.screen.width : 560
                }
                arePiecesDraggable={true}
                // position={'start'}
                animationDuration={200}
                customBoardStyle={{
                    borderRadius: '4px',
                    boxShadow: '0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
                }}
                customDarkSquareStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#A1B57D' }}
                customLightSquareStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#F7F7EE' }}
                customPieces={customPieces()}
                ref={chessboardRef}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually the author of this package so maybe I can help.

The package utilises [react-dnd](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/about) to handle dragging and dropping. This comes with different "Backends" for handling dragging and dropping on Mobile devices or Browsers.

react-chessboard has its own logic to try to load the correct backend for you automatically. But in case you want to override it with your own, or set a specific one, you can use the prop to pass it in yourself. That's all there is to it really, here's some code used in the package for more reference.

```
const backend = customDndBackend || (isMobile ? TouchBackend : HTML5Backend);
```